# jquery append something to each element that matches an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

need some of your expert help!

I have a page which contains multiple 'div#gridContainer p' elements. Basically I want to find ONLY the ones where p contains the word 'Delivery' and then append the variable 'delivery' to all the elements that match.

This is my code so far but it doesn't target only the elements that contain 'delivery'

```
if ($('div#gridContainer p:contains("Delivery")').length > 0) {
var delivery = 'image';
$('.deal_img').append(delivery);      
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: You have multiple paragraphs within the `#gridContainer` element, or you have multiple elements with the same `id` (which is invalid HTML, and JavaScript won't work as you want it to)? And by "append the variable 'delivery'" you mean you want to add the word in that variable to the end of the `p` element, or after the `Delivery` word?

Comment: Hi David, my page has multiple gridContainer id's with a P child element. The page can't be changed so if it's invalid html nothing I can do, just have to work around it.

Comment: Don't work around the symptoms, treat the disease. Also, a sample of your HTML would be rather useful if you really want help.

Comment: If there are multiple divs with the id of gridContainer, jQuery is only going to find the first one.  Because there can only be one id of gridContainer per page.

Comment: i'd love to treat the disease but it's not possible, we don't have access to change the code. currently my jquery is finding all of them but I only want to append 'delivery' to the ones that contain the word 'delivery'

Comment: You are using ID when you should be using CSS class.  ID's are supposed to be unique; used only once (regardless of object type) within a document.  If you want to identify something that occurs multiple times, it's best in most cases to simply use a class.  In your case, that would be <div class=gridContainer"> as the wrapper for your paragraphs.

Comment: It's not possible to change the code on my page. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: I just posted a working solution, tested in several browsers. If that doesn't work, then you may need to go "up" a bit in the DOM to get the parent element and traverse back downward from there.

Comment: ATTN DOWN-VOTERS: There's no reason to down-vote this user. He/She can't do anything about the messed up DOM ID tagging and is just asking for help. Let's be a bit more welcoming.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear that you cannot access the generating code to fix the bad HTML output. Multiple uses of an ID is just asking for trouble.  But I think the following single-line jQuery call will produce the affect you're looking for: `$('div#gridContainer p:contains("Delivery") span.deal_img').append('image');`

Live example, tested in Firefox 17, IE8, and Chrome 30:

```
<div id="gridContainer"><p>This paragraph contains the word Delivery<span class="deal_img"></span>.</p></div>
<div id="gridContainer"><p>This paragraph does not contain the key word<span class="deal_img"></span>.</p></div>
<div id="gridContainer"><p>This paragraph also contains the word Delivery<span class="deal_img"></span>.</p></div>
<div id="gridContainer"><p>Neither does this paragraph does not contain the key word<span class="deal_img"></span>.</p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('div#gridContainer p:contains("Delivery") span.deal_img').append('image');
</script>
```

**UPDATE**: I've slightly tweaked my answer.  Also, since it seems you likely want to append an image to the `<span>` with class of '"deal_img"' I've added a [JSFiddle with a more comprehensive JQuery solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mZNen/5/)

Answer (score 0):

One approach (and I would strongly, *strongly* recommend you do whatever you can to amend your HTML to be standards compliant, if only to make your work a great deal easier and the results more predictable and cross-browser compatible):

```
var text = 'image';
$('div[id="gridContainer"] p').each(function(i,e){
    var self = e;
    $(self).find('.deal-img').text(function(index,oldText){
        return self['textContent' || 'innerText'].indexOf('Delivery') > -1 ? text : oldText;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Dkr3v/1/).

The above is based on the following HTML, since you declined to post any of your own in order to help us to help you:

```
<div id="gridContainer">
    <p>Delivery</p>
    <p>Something else entirely</p>
</div>
<div id="gridContainer">
    <p>Delivery <span class="deal-img">I have <em>no</em> idea about most of this question</span>
    </p>
    <p>Something else entirely</p>
</div>
<div id="gridContainer">
    <p>Something else entirely</p>
</div>
<div id="gridContainer">
    <p>Delivery <span class="deal-img">guessing where this element should go</span>
    </p>
    <p>Something else entirely</p>
</div>
```

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: This is a better answer, but like David said it's better to write your HTML to have a class instead of an ID.

Comment: I've been doing JQuery a while and I can't figure out why you assigned "e" to a var called "self" (which could be confused for the native javascript object of the same name) or why you used `$(self)` instead of the native `$(this)` that would not have required the extra code?